# Свой контейнер или как добавить функционал

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, и снова у меня эта проблема. Мне нужно сделать свой контейнер похожий на map,  но сохраняющий в памяти только ключ, а value  записывающий в файл, название коего является ключем.

При `mymap[999] = 100;` 999 идет в АВЛ дерево, а потом создается файл с именем 999, и в него сохраняется значение 100.

проблема в том что мне нужно, дабы можно было провести такое действие:

*Менять в методе `modify` я ничего не могу.*

```
   void modify(int& a) {// базовый метод
    a += 5;
}

//Желаемый функционал
myMap[2] = 20;
int c = 30;
myMap[3] = с;
modify(myMap[2]); //меняет значение myMap[2]
int a = myMap[1];
int b = myMap[2];
assert(b == 25);//проверяем изменилось ли
myMap[2] = myMap[2] + 20;//снова меняем значение
```

При `modify(myMap[2]);`, значение в `myMap[2]` тоже должно меняться, а следовательно и в файле.

Я понимаю что для `mymap[999] = 100;` нужен прокси класс возвращаемый контейнером. Но для `modify(myMap[2]);` и `myMap[2] = myMap[2] + 20;` прокси не подходит. Возможно у всех прокси одного ключа можно сделать общую память, но я не знаю как.

Сам контейнер щас выглядит так:

```
template <typename Key, typename FileType, class Compare = std::less<Key>>
class PersistentMap {
public:
    typedef int size_type;
    typedef std::pair<Key, FileType> value_type;
    typedef FileType mapped_type;
    typedef AVL_Tree<Key, FileType> tree;

private:
    std::string dirName;
    tree *strom;
    Compare comp;
public:

    typedef typename tree::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename tree::const_iterator const_iterator;

    PersistentMap(std::string ag);

    const mapped_type operator[] (Key key);

    std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& a);
    //...
}
```

Буду рад совету, как это реализовать(возможно примеру).

Уже очень давно не могу решить данную проблему.

**UPD** 
может создать стак, в котором будут значения, и после уничтожения последней инстанции прокси данного ключа сохранять значение? (надеюсь внятно объяснил проблему)

**UPD_2**

Я знаю что на данный момент код ужасно структурирован, и кое где не логичен.
`PersistentMap.hpp` состоит из `PersistenMap+AVL_Tree` я просто их разделил на 2 примера, так как Авл щас не имеет значения, так же они находятся в неймспейсе `lib`.

[PersistentMap](http://pastebin.com/ttwuuyu3)

[AVL_Tree](http://pastebin.com/XMdXnm8L)

[Main.cpp](http://pastebin.com/rSZpgqYU)

В данный момент у меня при `modify(myMap[2]);` увеличивается значение в `myMap[2]` но вот с `myMap[2] = myMap[2] + 20;` проблема, так как левый объект деструктора рушится раньше правого, и перезаписывается.

**P.S.**

Задание относящиеся к прокси:

Вы можете вернуть экземпляр прокси-класса, который заботится о сохранении / загрузке правильных значений

1. наимплементуйте неявные операторы преобразования
2. наимплементуйте конструкторы, операторы присваивания
3. решение будет корректным в случае, когда несколько прокси разделяют
   общее хранилище данных

Comment: Я Вам уже говорил, что не меняя метод `modify` Ваша задача не имеет решения.

Comment: а если иметь стак, в котором будут находиться value актуальных прокси. и только после уничтожения последнего прокси сохранять значение в файл? Возможен ли такой вариант? И если да, как его реализовать?

Comment: В деструкторе proxy можно производить запись в файл, но это, во-первых, грязный костыль, во-вторых, очень ненадёжно. Вы, скорее всего, просто не так поняли задание. Не мог Вам преподаватель дать такого задания, если он сам хоть что-то в C++ понимает.

Comment: Обновил пост, внеся конкретику и примеры кода, пусть и фиговые.

Answer (score 1):

Я не готов дать полный ответ, потому как нет минимально компилируемого примера, но следующее утверждение не совсем корректно:

> Но для `modify(myMap[2]);` и `myMap[2] = myMap[2] + 20;` прокси не подходит.

Вот вам прокси, который вполне себе умеет эмулировать хранимый тип, по крайней мере в трёх вышеперечисленных сценариях:

```
template<typename T>
struct ValueProxy
{
    ValueProxy(T& v)
        : value(v)
    {
    }

    operator T&()
    {
        return value;
    }

    operator const T&() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    ValueProxy& operator=(const T& nv)
    {
        value = nv;
        return *this;
    }

    T& value;
};
```

Пример использования:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
struct SomeMap
{
    // Helpers
    using parent_t = std::map<Key, Value>;
    parent_t holder;

    // Part of interest
    ValueProxy<Value> operator[](const Key& key)
    {
        return {holder[key]};
    }
};
```

А вот проверки: http://ideone.com/DBTILc - тут видно, что вызов `modify()` успешно проходит, ровно как и `mymap[2] = mymap[2] + 100;`

Всё остальное, как мне кажется, дело техники. Ну или опубликуйте компилируемый пример своего мапа.

Comment: Прочитайте вопрос внимательнее, после выполнения функция `modify`, автор хочет, чтобы значение обновилось не только в дереве, что не является проблемой, но и в файле, поверх которого это дерево и построено.

Comment: @ixSci Это задел. А как решить - дело автора. Как минимум, кешировать оригинальное значение и в деструкторе прокси сравнивать его с актуальным - если поменялось, делать запись в файл. Да, тут можно потерять промежуточные результаты, если объект прокси будет долгоживущим. Второй вариант - при создании прокси открывать файл, делать ему `mmap()` или `CreateFileMapping` (или найти какую-то кросс-платформенную библиотеку которая абстрагирует от платформы) и, соответственно играться уже с отображением - есть адрес памяти, а значит для работы не будет никаких отличий от простой переменной.

Comment: Это всё не подходит и задача тут как раз не в том, чтобы прокси написать, а в том, чтобы отработала запись в файл. `mmap` и прочее системное API к C++ отношения не имеет, а у автора, насколько я понял, задача лежит именно в области C++ — это учебная задача. С деструктором вариант косой и убогий, но, возможно, с некоторыми оговорками его можно тут применить. Но тогда он должен быть у Вас в ответе, т.к. в текущем виде он(ответ) вообще не отвечает на вопрос автора.

Comment: @ixSci, автор не дал минимальной компилируемой реализации, в которой можно было бы какие-то изменения сделать, а писать самому слой асбтракции - желания особого нет, собственно, я об этом и написал. Опубликует - дополню. Отвечать только в рамках учебной задачи, а не возможных решений вообще - тоже странное ограничение для данного ресурса, тем более, что конкретно в этом после таких ограничений не было наложено.

Comment: Я обновил пост, добавил примеры кода, ужасно структурированного, но надеюсь понятного. Целью было написать `PersistentMap.hpp` коий будет работать с `main.cpp`